# How can I download first version of my app from google play console?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

1 year ago I launched my app on google play store and after almost 50 updates it looks very different. I don't have the first version of my app and I want to preserve the first version. Is there a way to download first version of the app?

Can someone please guide me through this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can "you just have to login using the **super user**":

1- Select your APP

2- Go to   >> APP bundle explorer (you will find a list of all your app version)

3- Choose the version you want

4-  you will be redirected to a details page for that specific app

5-  Choose Downloads Tab and from there you will be able to download (original abb file) or copy a shareable link

[image]